# Trying to create a loop that outputs a pyramid pattern out of stars and underscores based on user's input

Tags: loops

I'm trying to make it so the user will input an odd number of stars on the bottom row of the pyramid.  The program will build that pyramid using only odd integers less than the one input.  On the outside of the pyramid are underscores.

```
String result = "";
int sideWidth = -1, midWidth = -1;
for (int i=1; i<=numSymbols ; i++) 
{ 
    for (int j=numSymbols; j>i; j--)
    {
        System.out.print("_");
    }
    for (int k=1; k<=(i * 2) -1; k++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
return result;
```

Expected output if user puts 7:

```
___*___
__***__
_*****_
*******
```

What I actually got if user puts 7:

```
______*
_____***
____*****
___*******
__*********
_***********
*************
```

Comment: Consider adding language tag(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `numSymbols / 2 + 1` instead of `numSymbols` as you need 4 rows only for 7 `numSymbols`. Also, The `_` loop should be like this `j = numSymbols / 2; j >= i` and repeated twice; one before the stars and one after them. Finally, you don't need to use 'k'.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numSymbols / 2 + 1; i++) 
{ 
    for (int j = numSymbols / 2; j >= i; j--)
    {
        System.out.print("_");
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= i * 2 - 1; j++)
    {
       System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (int j = numSymbols / 2; j >= i; j--)
    {
        System.out.print("_");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

For a simpler form:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numSymbols; i += 2) 
{ 
    for (int j = numSymbols / 2; j >= i / 2; j--)
        System.out.print("_");
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
       System.out.print("*");
    for (int j = numSymbols / 2; j >= i / 2; j--)
        System.out.print("_");
    System.out.println();
}
```